# Decomposing planar Hamiltonian graphs

Tags: graphs, planar-graphs

I have the following the statement and I have to prove whether it is true or not.

> Given a planar and Hamiltonian graph $\mathbb{G} = (V, E)$, show that we can partition $E = E_1 \cup E_2 = E$ so that $G_1 = (V, E_1)$ and $G_2 = (V, E_2)$ are both connected and [outerplanar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outerplanar_graph) graphs.

I have tested the statement for few graphs and it seems correct to me, but I am not sure how can I use the property of the Hamiltonian cycle to decompose the graph into two sub-graphs.

I appreciate any hint!

Comment: What is the connection between $\mathbb{V},\mathbb{E},V,E_1,E_2$?

Comment: Sorry, I have just edited the post

Comment: Can you find a connected non-Hamiltonian planar graph for which this fails?